# Firebase - storage images on form submit. React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload image to firebase storage with this code:

```
const firebase = useFirebase();
      const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
       // state.title && dispatch(createItems(state));

        firebase
          .storage()
          .ref(`images/${state.title}`)
          .child(state.title)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(url => setState({ ...state, avatarURL: url }));
      };
```

And it's not working. Almost the same code works fine with react-firebase-file-uploader. Does any anyone has idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Doing``.ref(`images/${state.title}`).child(state.title)`` means that you'll have `state.title` in the file path as well as being the file name. Is that what you want?

Comment: Actually it doean't matter what the file name would be. For know it can be the same and I'll think about it later. The question is why it's not uploading to firebase at all.

Comment: "The question is why it's not uploading to firebase at all." -> See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
 firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`images/${state.title}`)
      .child(state.title)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => setState({ ...state, avatarURL: url }));
```

you are **not** uploading a file to Cloud Storage but you are just getting "a long lived download URL for the object" represented by the `` .ref(`images/${state.title}`).child(state.title) `` [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference), through the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl) method.

If you want to upload a file you need to use the [`put()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) method.

Comment: I've tried to use put() and also set() but nothing worked :/ only work the first code with file-uploader package.